# Why does passing high number to a function with recursion makes my console stop responding?

Tags: c++

```
int summation(int x) {
    if(x > 0) {
        return x += summation(x-1);
    }
    return x;
}
```

The function works fine with smaller values but close to 1 million it crushes my console.

```
cout << summation(1000000);
```

I am curious as to why it happens.

Comment: Every time you call a function you allocate space on the stack. Big number => a lot of functions calls => a lot of stack allocation => Boom

Comment: Ironically, what you're asking about is a stackoverflow ...

Comment: btw most simple examples for recursion are bad ones. In real code you wanted to write it like that: `int summation(int n) { return ((n-1)*n)/2;}`

Comment: So recursion is easy to implement but takes a lot more memory?

Comment: Recursion has it's place, for example it's an easy way to do a merge sort implementation; but you have to find a way to ensure that the number of recursions you do is minimal and ideally with some limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion have that problem. For each call, the program must save the data in the stack. So when the number is so big, the data that has been saved is big too. You probably see a stackoverflow problem in your code.